# /bin/sh symbolic link not working properly

Tags: shell, zsh, symlink, i3

I am using i3, and by default, it uses `sh` when starting process with the i3 config `exec` command. This is fine and dandy, but that means the environmental variables created in my .zshrc do not get carried over to child process of i3 (pretty much any program I open).

To fix this, I tried changing the `/bin/sh` symbolic link to point to `/bin/zsh` instead like so:

```
$ which sh
/bin/sh
$ sudo rm /bin/sh
$ sudo ln -s /bin/zsh /bin/sh
```

This creates the symbolic link I expected it to:

```
$ ls -la /bin/sh    
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8 Mar 13 22:16 /bin/sh -> /bin/zsh
$ which sh
/bin/sh
```

However, when I try to run `sh`, `sh` starts intead of `zsh`. The same occurs when I run `/bin/sh`. I logged out and then logged back in. It did not change anything.

`/bin/zsh` and `zsh` commands start `zsh` as expected.

Comment: From the manual page: *"Zsh tries to emulate sh or ksh when it is invoked as sh or ksh  respectively"* - are you sure that's not what's happening here?

Comment: Wow, you are completely correct. Sorry, I should have looked more carefully at the man page or experimented with the shell more.

Comment: It's still a fair question imho - in particular, perhaps one of the shell experts might be able to explain exactly what features/behviors  are and are not emulated

Comment: @steeldriver Interestingly enough though, it seems to mimic `sh` to the point that it doesn't even look at the .zshrc file, so none of my environmental variables get setup. Maybe I'll just explicitly use `exec zsh -c "some command"` in the i3 config file instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out `zsh` was launching properly, but it was mimicking `sh`. I should have read the man page more carefully. As @steeldriver pointed out, the man page states: "*Zsh tries to emulate sh or ksh when it is invoked as sh or ksh respectively*"

Comment: Yeah, that's kinda the point of `/bin/sh`, to be the POSIX shell.

Comment: @Kusalananda I see that now. Without reading the man page, I don't think it is straight forward to assume that an application would launch differently based on the name of the symbolic link to it. As a user with about a medium level of Linux experience, I would assume that symbolic link would launch an application the same way regardless of the name of the symbolic link. I now see that that is not true. Would the same behavior be expected if `/usr/bin/zsh` was copied to `/bin/sh`?

Comment: The same behaviour would be expected.  The `/bin/sh` shell (no matter what shell actually implements it) is expected to be a POSIX shell capable of running standard compliant shell scripts.  Your issue with the environment variables has nothing to do with what shell is being used. You are expecting `i3` to know about your variables even though `i3` itself never inherited them from your `.zshrc` file (it was not started from an environment where that file had been parsed, obviously).

Comment: Since this particular question is about the behaviour of `zsh` when started as `sh`, I'd suggest that you open a new question about the issue with the environment variables specifically. You would describe how your start `i3` and what you expect to happen with regards to environment variables when you launch child processes from its config (and what actually does happen instead).